# Firebase InstanceID Token Refresh delay on ios device

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging in my iOS application. Everything seems to work just fine, except one thing, the fact that it takes almost 10 seconds from the app to launch to get the device token refreshed in Firebase.

I have added this code to the `application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method in the App Delegate:

```
[FIRApp configure];

//Add an observer for handling a token refresh callback.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshCallback:) name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
```

And this is the `tokenRefreshCallback:` method:

```
- (void)tokenRefreshCallback:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

    if ([[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token] != NULL) {
        [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/news"];
        NSLog(@"Subscribed to news topic");
    }

    //Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempting before having a token
    [self connectToFirebase];

}
```

And this is the relevant part of logger:

```
2016-10-13 14:36:23.844 My-App[1111] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2016-10-13 14:36:26.492 My-App[1111:2222222] InstanceID token: (null)
2016-10-13 14:36:32.732 My-App[1111:2222222] InstanceID token: c1kmaskdmj...(the actual device token)
```

1. Why is the `tokenRefreshCallback:` called when the InstanceID is (null)?
2. Why does it take almost 10 seconds before an actual token is retrieved?

Answer (score 2):

In my case.  I had the same problem when using deeplinking to navigate between screens.

Without that all was working good.

this was working for me.  In  application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I call  [self configureFirebase];

```
- (void)configureFirebase {
    [FIRApp configure];
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        }];

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
#endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

also I implement this messages:

```
// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    if (!(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)) {
        [AuthenticationController showAuthenticationViews:self.window];
    }
    [self readNotification:userInfo];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    [self readNotification:userInfo];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    [self readNotification:userInfo];
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    [self readNotification:userInfo];
    completionHandler();
}
#endif
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    // Print full message
    //NSLog(@"%@", remoteMessage.appData);
}
#endif
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    //NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    // NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    [self connectToFcm];

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
- (void)connectToFcm {
    // Won't connect since there is no token
    if (![[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]) {
        return;
    }

    // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:notificationTopic];
            //NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //  NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
// the InstanceID token.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    // [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
    BOOL automatic = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"automaticLogin"] boolValue];
    if (!automatic) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"automaticLogin"];
        [self moveToInit];
    }
}

// [START connect_on_active]
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self connectToFcm];
}
// [END connect_on_active]

// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    // NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]

#pragma mark - Process notifications



- (void)readNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
   //read your notification
}

-(void)readLaunchWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions{
    if (launchOptions[notificationKey]) {
        [self readNotification:launchOptions[notificationKey]];
    }
}
```